# listMonth FullCalendar view: split duration for long events

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I need to show duration when i'm using listMonth view in fullCalendar.

Now i'm using this (same for example test image posted) where I get start and end of a event. So if the event start in a day, and finish on another day (next day) i get same phrase for both rows. See pic.

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {

        if ( view.type == "listMonth" ) {

            var title = element.find( '.fc-list-item-title' );
            title.html( event.title + ': from  ' + event.dateInit + ' to ' + event.dateEnd);

        }

    },
```

I'd like to split duration of a event based on the day. FOr example Event "Malattia" start on August 03 and ends on August 04 so, i need to calculate duration inside August 03, and calculate duration inside August 04 like image example edited (bottom).

My variable are:

`event.dateInit` and `event.dateEnd` in the format: `"Y-m-d H:i:s"`

I don't know how calculate duration of event "splitted" in multiple days.

[image]

I link a jsfiddle to test: http://jsfiddle.net/s7t2bc12/101/